# Should we mention a Orphan Page in robots txt file to disallow crawling?

Tags: web-crawler, robots.txt

We have a orphan page on our website, this should be accessed only when someone receives a link to it on their email. We don't want this page to be indexed in search and don't want it to appear in any search.
We have already excluded this page from out sitemap.xml. Should we have to mention this page url in robots.txt to disallow crawl?

Comment: if you want to prevent a page from being crawled, you add it to robots.txt.

Comment: You should have posted that as an answer. That's how it is done (upvote & I will upvote your answer, if you post one - doing so will help others who read this question in future)

Comment: @Evert - since it is not referenced from any pages on the site and also not specified in sitemap.xml. Will it still be crawled by bots?
We are trying to hide this url from users too. If we specify this in robots.txt, someone might look it up and try to it the url. We want to avoid that as well.

Having said that, we also don't want this to be crawled.

Comment: @KamalKishor if people visit it, there's a chance it ends up on random logs and gets crawled. There's lots of evidence for this behavior. If there is a security reason that should prevent users from accessing this, a secret url may not be sufficient. Depending on how sensitive this is, you might need to have authentication. You can however use wildcards in robots rules so even if it appears in `robots.txt` it still wouldn't have a full url.